# How to increase speed of timer object using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode6, nstimer

I am using an `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` object but cannot increase the speed of the clock to faster than 1/1000. I have tried invalidating the clock and re-creating. timer2 & timer3 work fine on the iOS simulator but does not work when testing on iPhone 5s device. Speed stays always on 1/1000 even when firing timer2 or timer3. Below is my definition:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.001, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

timer2 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.002, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

timer3 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.003, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: You are setting your timer to fire 1000 times per second

Comment: All your timers use the same selector, how are you supposed to distinguish the timers?

Comment: Perhaps I have not been clear enough in my question. The issue I am faced with is my iPhone test device cannot handle an interval number greater than 0.001. When this is set to 0.002 or 0.003 the speed on the iPhone remains at 0.001. It works fine on the iPhone simulator however. I need to understand if there is a limitation with the iPhone or a coding issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change a timer. If you want a timer running at a different interval, you have to invalidate and destroy the existing timer and replace it with a new one. That's quite a common thing to do; timers are lightweight objects.

Comment: Matt thanks for your response. I have taken your advice and this now works perfectly when running in the simulator, however the speed of the timer does not change when playing on device? Let me know if pasting the code in here would help?